# Fill some inputs from one dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jsp like this:

```js
$("select[name='numbers']").change(function() {
  var str = $('#numbers option:selected').text();
  var ret = str.split(" ");
  var str1 = ret[0];
  var str2 = ret[1];
  var str3 = ret[3];
  $("first").val(str1);
  $("second").val(str2);
  $("last").val(str3);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="numbers" name="numbers">
  <option value="1 2 3">1 2 3</option>
  <option value="4 5 6">4 5 6</option>
  <option value="7 8 9">7 8 9</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
First: <input id="first" name="first" type="text"/><br/>
Second: <input id="second" name="second" type="text"/><br/>
Last: <input id="last" name="last" type="text"/>
```

What I would like to do is fill the inputs like this:

- if 1 2 3 option is selected, write 1 inside first input, 2 inside second input, 3 inside last input;
- if 4 5 6 option is selected, write 4 inside first input, 5 inside second input, 6 inside last input;
- if 7 8 9 option is selected, write 7 inside first input, 8 inside second input, 9 inside last input;

I tried in this way but it's not working: https://jsfiddle.net/L1xj7uge/ I think I'm selecting the dropdown list value in a wrong way but I don't know how to solve.

Comment: Updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L1xj7uge/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L1xj7uge/3/)**.

You should add the `id` sign `#` in the selector of those lines to refer to `id` attribute :

```
$("#first").val(str1);
$("#second").val(str2);
$("#last").val(str3);
```

And also the index of `str3` should be `2` not `3`, so :

```
var str3 = ret[3];
```

Should be :

```
var str3 = ret[2];
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("select[name='numbers']").change(function() {
  var str = $('#numbers option:selected').text();
  var ret = str.split(" ");
  var str1 = ret[0];
  var str2 = ret[1];
  var str3 = ret[2];

  $("#first").val(str1);
  $("#second").val(str2);
  $("#last").val(str3);

}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="numbers" name="numbers">
  <option value="1 2 3">1 2 3</option>
  <option value="4 5 6">4 5 6</option>
  <option value="7 8 9">7 8 9</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
First: <input id="first" name="first" type="text"/><br/>
Second: <input id="second" name="second" type="text"/><br/>
Last: <input id="last" name="last" type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems in your code. Firstly the indexes of the array items would be `0`, `1`, and `2`. Also you missed the `#` prefix of the id selector.

Also note that you can simply retrieve the `val()` of the select, and also make the logic more generic by putting a common class on the `input` elements and matching the values by index, like this:

```js
$("select[name='numbers']").change(function() {
  var $inputs = $('input.foo');
  $('#numbers').val().split(" ").forEach(function(t, i) {
    $inputs.eq(i).val(t);
  });
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="numbers" name="numbers">
  <option value="1 2 3">1 2 3</option>
  <option value="4 5 6">4 5 6</option>
  <option value="7 8 9">7 8 9</option>
</select><br/><br/> 

First: <input id="first" name="first" type="text" class="foo" /><br/> 
Second: <input id="second" name="second" type="text" class="foo" /><br/> 
Last: <input id="last" name="last" type="text" class="foo" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There were a few typos --

- `ret[3]` should be `ret[2]`
- you have to add the `#` before the words `first`, `second`, and `last` in the selectors
- use `.val()` to get the selected text from a select element

```js
$("#numbers").on("change", function() {
  var str = $('#numbers').val();
  var ret = str.split(" ");
  var str1 = ret[0];
  var str2 = ret[1];
  var str3 = ret[2];
  $("#first").val(str1);
  $("#second").val(str2);
  $("#last").val(str3);
}).trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="numbers" name="numbers">
  <option value="1 2 3">1 2 3</option>
  <option value="4 5 6">4 5 6</option>
  <option value="7 8 9">7 8 9</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>First:
<input id="first" name="first" type="text" />
<br/>Second:
<input id="second" name="second" type="text" />
<br/>Last:
<input id="last" name="last" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#numbers').change(function() {
  var getoption = $('#numbers').val().toString().split(' ')
  $('#first').val(getoption[0])
  $('#second').val(getoption[1])
  $('#last').val(getoption[2])
}).change()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="numbers" name="numbers">
        <option value="1 2 3">1 2 3</option>
        <option value="4 5 6">4 5 6</option>
        <option value="7 8 9">7 8 9</option>
     </select>
       <br/>
       <br/>
     First: <input id="first" name="first" type="text"/><br/>
     Second: <input id="second" name="second" type="text"/><br/>
     Last: <input id="last" name="last" type="text"/>
```

Try this

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Add a change trigger function to the select box and split the selected values with the space and assign the split array elements to the corresponding text boxes.

Try this:

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <title>table</title>
    <script src="moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <select id="numbers" name="numbers">
    <option value="1 2 3">1 2 3</option>
    <option value="4 5 6">4 5 6</option>
    <option value="7 8 9">7 8 9</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    First: <input id="first" name="first" type="text"/><br/>
    Second: <input id="second" name="second" type="text"/><br/>
    Last: <input id="last" name="last" type="text"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#numbers').change(function(){
               var valueArr = $(this).val().split(' ');
               $('#first').val(valueArr[0]);
               $('#second').val(valueArr[1]);
               $('#last').val(valueArr[2]);
            });
        });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

you almost done, just small problem in jquery element selection by id.

```
//see this
$("#numbers").change(function() {
    var str = $('#numbers option:selected').text();
    var ret = str.split(" ");
    var str1 = ret[0];
    var str2 = ret[1];
    var str3 = ret[2];
    $("#first").val(str1);
    $("#second").val(str2);
    $("#last").val(str3);
});
```